# I get the same job title for multiple jobs when using beautifulSoup to scrape a company site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a script using beautifulSoup in Python which I'm using to scrape job positions from a website (I have permission).

**The Issue**

The scraper works well, however for different job positions it returns the same title, whereas they should be different pending on the job posting.

**The code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

base = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"
url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/1143"

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
links = soup.select("a")

for link in links:
    if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
        res = requests.get(base + link.get("href")).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
        title = soup.select_one("h1.page-intro__title").get_text() if 
soup.select_one("h1.section__title") else ""
        overview = soup.select_one("p.page-intro__longDescription").get_text()
        details = soup.select_one("div.rte").get_text()
        print(title, link, details)
```

**The Outcome**

For some reason all of the job positions are given the same title, but everything else is unique (url, copy etc.) for the job posting.

```
TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-to-improve-value-creation-and-finance-functions/"

TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-with-unique-competences-within-hr-excellence/"

TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-within-supply-chain-management/"

TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-within-leadership-development-or-change-management/"

TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-to-help-our-customers-succeed-with-it/"
```

**Expected Outcome**

The outcome should be like the below, where the titles are unique:

```
TITLE:    Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-within-leadership-development-or-change-management/"

TITLE:    Management Consultants to help our customers succeed with IT functions\r\n LINK href="/career/management-consultants-to-help-our-customers-succeed-with-it/"
```

**Edited**

Tried the below code, but still seeing the same title for all many of the positions:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

base = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"
url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/1143"

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')

for link in soup.select("a"):
    if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
        res = requests.get(base + link.get("href")).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
        try:
            title = soup.select_one("h1.page-intro__title").get_text().strip()
         except:
            title = ''
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply this, hope it will fix the issue:

```
title = soup.select_one("h1.page-intro__title").get_text() if soup.select_one("h1.section__title") else ""
```

And, you can also go like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

base = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"
url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/1143"

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')

for link in soup.select("a"):
    if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
        res = requests.get(base + link.get("href")).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
        try:
            title = soup.select_one("h1.page-intro__title").get_text().strip()
        except:
            title = ''
        print(title)
```

This is the result:

```
Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions
Management consultants with unique competences within Organisation & HR
Management consultants within supply chain management
Management consultants within leadership development or change management
Management consultants to help our customers succeed with IT
Management consultants within process improvement
```

**Updated result**

```
(u'Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions', <a 
class="box-link" href="/career/management-consultants-to-improve-value-
creation-and-finance-functions/">\n<h2 
(u'Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions', <a 
class="box-link" href="/career/management-consultants-with-unique-competences-
within-hr-excellence/">\n<h2 
(u'Management consultants to improve value creation and finance functions', <a 
class="box-link" href="/career/management-consultants-within-supply-chain-
```

management/">\n

Comment: Thanks for the input Shahin, however I still get the wrong output. I have used the exact code you provided above.

Comment: No problem , Palle Broe. Things happen. Would you be able to specify some titles among the scraped ones which are being parsed alike but in reality they are not; rather, they are different in the webpage?

Comment: Yes - I have edited the above output, which shows an example of the title being repeated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi!! I ran the code for three times and found the same results with not a single one duplicated. I could have helped if I could find some error. I'm confused why the same code behaves differently. See for yourself- here is the link for the results I've got. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uiukm6y8b8yrvql/Palle%20Broe.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thanks Shahin. So weird. Can you paste the code you ran in your answer above? Also do you have any idea why we might be getting different results?

Comment: Before execution I copied the code from the above post and the result you have seen already. Thanks. Btw, i don't really have any idea for this variation.